# socket.io catch any event in nodejs

Tags: node.js, socket.io

My reactjs app creates a socket.io connection to nodejs. Using socket.io  4.1.2 and I can see it in `connection` event on server side as follows;

```
const io = new Server(server);

io.on("connection", async (socket: Socket) => {
  console.log("CONNECTION...", socket.id);
  socket.onAny((event, ...args) => {
    console.log(`ANY ${event}`, socket.id);
  });
});
```

AFAIK, we can catch any event on server side. However,  `socket.onAny` never gets hit by any event after connection.  For example, when I close the browser, I saw below lines on server side. But `any` did not catch this disconnect event.

```
  socket.io:client client close with reason transport error +6m
  socket.io:socket closing socket - reason transport error +6m
  socket.io:client client close with reason transport close +1s
  socket.io:socket closing socket - reason transport close +1s
```

How can I catch all the events on server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's not stated in the documentation but I think `onAny` listener only counts for events "manually" emitted from the client socket. Like :

```js
// client
socket.emit("some-event");

// server
socket.onAny((event) => {
  console.log(`ANY $[event}`);
});

// will log "ANY some-event"
```

However, for the `disconnect` event you would need an additional listener, like:

```js
// server
socket.on("disconnect", (reason) => {
 // ...
});
```

Try emitting a few events from your client side and check if your `onAny` listener gets triggered. It should !

Comment: Thank you @Pascal, that makes sense.  Is it possible to watch ping & pong events maybe?

Comment: They removed the inbuilt "ping" / "pong" events : https://socket.io/docs/v4/migrating-from-2-x-to-3-0/#No-more-%E2%80%9Cpong%E2%80%9D-event-for-retrieving-latency you have to as well emit manually a "ping" event from client-side (best with volatile flag) and catch it with an `onAny` on the server side.

Comment: On the serverside, do we have only `connection` event? Would any reconnect on the clienr side upon, for example transport close, trigger this `connection` event on the serverside? Or do I need to handle such a reconnect manually?

Comment: Afaik the `connect` event on the server side is always triggered when a client connects, this includes "reconnecting". And yes on the server side you online have `connect` and `disconnect` events. However on the client side you have a few more events for the `Manager` https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-api/#Manager . By default a client always tries to reconnect automatically unless the disconnect reason is `io server disconnect` - then you have to reconnect manually : https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-api/#Event-%E2%80%98disconnect%E2%80%99 see here for example.

Comment: Are you looking to solve a specific problem ? The way you ask makes me believe you still looking for a solution to a problem :)

Comment: :-) Actually, what I'm doing is to handle those reconnects due to transport close or ping timeout. I saw something strange; when such a reconnect occurs on the client side, my `connection` handler on the server side did not get triggered time to time.  Trying to create a simpler demo on github.